# Решения задачи выглядят одинаково, но одно не проходит по времени

Tags: c++

Это проблема с сайта CSES "Concert Tickets"

https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1091/

Ниже мое решение

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define int long long
using namespace std;

multiset<int> h;

signed main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    int n, m;

    cin>>n>>m;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++ i)
    {
        int x;
        cin>>x;
        h.insert(x);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++ i)
    {
        int x;
        cin>>x;

        auto it = upper_bound(x);
        if (it != h.begin())
        {
            --it;
            cout<<*it<<"\n";
            h.erase(it);
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"-1\n";
        }
    }
}
```

А вот решение с сайта, которое проходит все тесты в отличие от моего(TL на 4). Не понимаю, что конкретно я написал не так, из-за чего не проходит на всех тестах

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

//variables used for the current problem
int n,m,h,t; multiset<int> tickets;

void solve() {
    cin >> n >> m;
    for (int i=0;i<n;++i){
        cin >> h; tickets.insert(h);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<m;++i){
        cin >> t;
        auto it = tickets.upper_bound(t);
        if (it==tickets.begin()){
            cout << -1 << "\n";
        }
        else{
            cout << *(--it) << "\n";
            tickets.erase(it);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык, это SO на русском

Comment: Английский попрактиковать захотел просто, чет забыл. Давно на сайте не был

Comment: `#define int long long` а это точно нужно?

Comment: точно. все значения до 1e9

Answer (score 0):

`auto it = upper_bound(x);`
КЕК upper_bound по всей памяти, получается